# RVM With JRuby 1.7.0 "Unknown Ruby Interpreter"

Tags: ruby, rvm, jruby, bundler

I setup a basic Rails application with the following Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'    
ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.0'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
```

Whenever I change into the project directory I get the following message:

> Unknown ruby interpreter version:
>   '1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.0'.

I'm running RVM 1.16.17 and have installed 'jruby-1.7.0'. Is my Gemfile engine misconfigued or do I need to change something in RVM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RVM has limited support of the ruby directive, you can use comment to overwrite what will be used by RVM:

```
#ruby=jruby-1.7.0
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer... is that line to be added below the other one?

Comment: it makes no difference the comment takes precedence over the expression (as it was the first one supported and the expression might contain ruby code which would require hiding  with the comment)