# RVM reports Gemfile ruby as not installed

Tags: ruby, rvm, jruby

In my Gemfile, I have specified:

```
ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.9'
```

But entering my Rails project directory makes `rvm` throw up this error:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/petey/rails/kotoba/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.9 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.9'
```

However, I do have jruby 1.7.9 installed:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.7.9 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rvm use jruby
Using /home/petey/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.9

$ ruby -v
jruby 1.7.9 (1.9.3p392) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_25-b30 [linux-amd64]
```

In fact, I can even select it with `rvm use jruby` and rails works fine.

Is there a problem with the ruby directive in the Gemfile?

I followed the [official specification](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile_ruby.html), which has a very similar example.

---

**Edit:** On running `rvm install ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.9` at the prompt, rvm proceeds to install `ruby-1.9.3-p484`. And once again, it shows the same error message on entering the project directory:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/petey/rails/kotoba/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.9 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.9'
```

Comment: What happens if you run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.9`? Does it tell you it's already installed?

Comment: @AlexSiri It starts downloading `ruby-1.9.3-p484` (MRI and not jruby). I'll let it finishing downloading, check rvm's behavior and report back.

Comment: It's Probably not going to download or use the jruby version

Comment: @AlexSiri Yeah, it doesn't seem to. Updated my post.

Comment: I think you should better create a `.ruby-version` file, which rvm will use before loading bundler, the Gemfile, and any other files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344639/1825792) SO answer:

> RVM has limited support of the ruby directive, you can use comment to overwrite what will be used by RVM.

---

By adding:

```
#ruby=jruby-1.7.9
```

to the Gemfile just below the `ruby` directive, rvm seems to be able to pick the right ruby:

```
$ cd kotoba
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/petey/rails/kotoba/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

$ ruby -v
jruby 1.7.9 (1.9.3p392) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_25-b30 [linux-amd64]
```