# Specifying JRuby Version in Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I wasn't able to find a SO QA that could answer this.

I installed JRuby via `rvm install jruby` and then generated a new rails application. To allow for changing of the ruby version automatically via rvm, I discovered that Bundler allows you to add:

```
ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.12'
```

See here for [reference](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile_ruby.html). Since this is 1.3, I checked my Bundler version within my root app directory:

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.6.2
```

I'm assuming I have this functionality. Now, when I move onto adding this to Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.12'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
```

And then after running `cd .. && cd app` I received this issue:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore  /Users/benmorgan/Sites/sigma/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-1.9.3,engine:jruby,engine_version:1.7.12.
```

Do you know how to tell rvm to select the jruby version? Is it possible within the Gemfile?

Comment: Rvm didn't use to support this (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943906/rvm-reports-gemfile-ruby-as-not-installed )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as suggested by the comment already linking to [RVM reports Gemfile ruby as not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943906/rvm-reports-gemfile-ruby-as-not-installed)

RVM's support for resolving a Ruby "engine" from the *Gemfile* is limited and does not match how Heroku is using (parsing) the directive.

if you really want to have it both in the *Gemfile* use a comment for RVM e.g.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
#ruby=jruby-1.7.12
if ENV["JRUBY"] || RUBY_PLATFORM == "java"
  ruby "1.9.3", engine: "jruby", engine_version: "1.7.12"
end

gem "rails", "~> 4.1.1"
# ...
```